# Resnet50 to classify human action on videos in PyTorch

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to use a Resnet50 to classify human actions following [this](https://github.com/kenshohara/3D-ResNets-PyTorch) repo. I’ve implemented my own DataLoader to produce my batches from [this](http://crcv.ucf.edu/data/UCF_YouTube_Action.php) dataset. Unlike the repo, I am not using the 3D CNN, but a simple PyTorch Resnet50. Thus, I need a 4D tensor input to feed the net, instead I have a 5D (Batch size, channels size, stacked images, Height, Width), where the stacked images are frames from the video in different time steps. Should I stop stacking this images and just iterate over the list of 4D tensors?